# Problem with bones (enexpected scaling when rotating)

Tags: armature, bones

To the point:

I'm trying to edit Unreal advanced vehicle mesh found in this template ( https://docs.unrealengine.com/latest/INT/Engine/Physics/Vehicles/DoubleWishboneVehicle/index.html#overview ) to my own model but when I check to see if all the behaviors of rotation are similar to the original (using blender), I get this weird effect when trying to rotate the back wheels around the bones they are associated to (VisWheel_BL and VisWheel_BR). All the vertex groups are present and all other rotation behaviors act as they do in the original template but  the two back wheel are wrong and they are keeping me stuck. Can someone help me, please? Thanks in advance.

Here's the expected and the unexpeceted behavior: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YK8V10jKTPg&feature=youtu.be